# Is there a way to put the command prompt at the top of the terminal window?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I am wondering how to reverse the order of the prompt and the output for terminal and iTerm2 for macOS, but I can't seem to find the setting.

Comment: You want bottom|up for the output of everything in the shell?

Comment: Yes, I want to flip it. Do you know how to do it?